# Как лучше сделать форму?

Tags: php, yii2

Есть метод контроллера принимающий в path variables 2 параметра. Вызывать его надо обычным GET запросом (типа как по ссылке перейти). Никаких данных он больше не принимает. Выглядит он так:

`ArticleManagementController::actionChangeStatus($article_id, $status_id)`

Соответственно вызов, например: `/article/<article_id>/management/status/change/<status_id>`

Но вот проблема status_id у меня выводится в обычном select элементе (выпадающим списком из статусов). И есть кнопка сохранить которая должна отправить запрос. Я никак не решу как сделать отправку. Т.е. select - это же элемент формы, а мне надо это число (status_id) в ссылку подставить.

Подскажите можно ли это сделать как-то по простому без джаваскрипта? У меня все формы тут обычные просто. JS даже еще нигде не приходилось использовать.

[image: пример формы]

Comment: Похоже никак. Можно научить ArticleManagementController::actionChangeStatus принимать `$_GET` или `$_POST` переменные, а форму просто сабмитить.

Comment: @IvanBolnikh но мне кажется что тут удобнее когда все передается в ссылке. Ведь тут всего две переменные нужны. Зачем тут делать передачу модели в теле? Еще новую модель придется клепать...

Comment: тогда нужен js, чтобы сформировать ссылку и перейти на нее.

Comment: @IvanBolnikh а как это на жс сделать? Я его очень плохо знаю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

У формы надо задать свойство method="GET" тогда все поля будут передаваться через урл.

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin([
    'action' => ['index'],
    'method' => 'get',
]); ?>
```

Comment: Это уже интересно, но будет ли он подставлять параметры в соответствии с роутером? Или он просто подставит их как `?article_id=1&status_id=2`? Просто у меня то там переменные передавались как path variables, т.е. `/article/1/management/status/change/2`.

Comment: Тогда прошу прощения так не получится. Упустил момент с ЧПУ шным урлом. Тогда только яваскрипт или менять логику метода на пост. Можно прописать actionChangeStatus($article_id, $status_id = null), а в коде уже, если $status_id === null искать ее в Yii::$app->request->post('status_id');

Answer (score -1):

Делегируйте создание ссылки другому методу:

```
createLinkAction()
{
    $link = sprintf('/article/%s/management/status/change/%s',
        $_GET['article_id'],$_GET['status_id']
    );
    $this->redirect($link);
}
```

Сабмитьте форму на метод - создатель ссылки