# Как сделать НЕ ЧПУ урл?

Tags: php, yii2

Вопрос в продолжение к [этому](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/738773/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D1%88%D0%B5-%D1%81%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D1%84%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%BC%D1%83). Я было временно сделал чтобы этот экшн принимал форму как объект, но быстро понял что это чрезвычайно неудобно в данном случае. Потому что такая форма с выбором статуса у меня только в одном месте, зато в куче других мест идет изменение статуса с явным его указанием без необходимости выбирать вручную. И мне приходится везде лепить формы вместо того чтобы сделать простую ссылку.

Насколько я понял чтобы не городить огород с JS которого у меня вообще нет в проекте ни строчки будет проще сделать конкретно этот урл не ЧПУ (чтобы он вызывался например так `/article/management/status/change?article_id=1&status_id=2`). Тогда я смогу эту форму отправлять GET запросом (просто прописав `method="get"` у формы).

Но все урлы в проекте у меня все равно должны оставаться ЧПУ. И enablePrettyUrl в конфиге стоит. Как же сделать его чтобы параметры именно так передавались? Не нахожу такого в доках. Подскажите пожалуйста.

P.S. Видел вариант где параметры читаются через `Yii::$app->request()->get()`, но неужели нет более удобного варианта? Чтобы параметры были явно объявлены в методе как обычно? Типа `actionChangeStatus($article_id, $status_id)`.

Comment: Могли бы Вы показать rule из UrlManager для этого роута?

Comment: @RTK В данный момент он такой: `/article/management/status/change' => 'article-management/change-status'`, был более ЧПУ-шный вариант который пришлось убрать `/article/<article_id>/management/status/change/<status_id>' => 'article-management/change-status'`

Answer (score 0):

Минутка наркомании. Поскольку мне очень срочно надо было решить этот вопрос, другого решения я не нашел, а ответа никто не пишет я решил его так:

```
private function get($key, $default = null) {
    $s = explode('?', Yii::$app->request->url);
    $s = explode('=', end($s));
    $keys = [];
    $values = [];

    foreach ($s as $index => $item) {
        if ($index % 2 == 0)
            $keys[] = $item;
        else
            $values[] = $item;
    }

    $get = array_combine($keys, $values);
    return ArrayHelper::getValue($get, $key, $default);
}

public function actionHello() {
    $name = $this->get('name', 'world');
    return "Hello $name!";
}
```

Теперь можно делать так: /hello?name=world